# In Nginx, how to redirect to another domain, but to also preserve the path AND the subdomain?

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect, subdomain

So, for instance, I have a domain `olddomain.com` and `newdomain.com`

Here's how I want requests redirects to work:

`sub.olddomain.com/hello/world -> sub.newdomain.com/hello/world`
`olddomain.com/hello/world     -> newdomain.com/hello/world`

There are many subdomains, so ideally I wouldn't want to create a rule for each one of them.

This seems like a solution:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name olddomain.com *.olddomain.com;
  rewrite ^(/)(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$2 permanent;
}
```

but it doesn't work with subdomains, since all subdomains would redirect to `newdomain.com/path` without regard for a subdomain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be looking for something like this:

```
if ($http_host ~ (.*)\.olddomain\.com) {
    set $subdomain $1;
    rewrite (.*)$ http://$subdomain.newdomain.com$1 permanent;
}
rewrite ^(/)(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$2 permanent;
```

These are my testcases

```
$ curl -I -H "Host: test1.olddomain.com" nginx1.tst
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 19:40:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://test1.newdomain.com/

$ curl -I -H "Host: test1.test2.olddomain.com" nginx1.tst
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 19:40:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://test1.test2.newdomain.com/

$ curl -I -H "Host: test1.test2.olddomain.com" nginx1.tst/with-something/appended.html
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 19:40:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://test1.test2.newdomain.com/with-something/appended.html

$ curl -I -H "Host: olddomain.com" nginx1.tst
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.4.4
Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 19:41:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://newdomain.com/
```